# Is it possible to connect a model object to a celery task?

Tags: python, sql, django, database, celery

I need to connect a celery task to a model objects.
For example, I need to create an object of a model

```
class AuthorPrice(models.Model):
    author = models.Charfield(default=0)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

I have a task.py

```
app = Celery()

@app.task
def create():
    new = AuthorPrice.object.create()
    new.author = John
    new.price = 30
    new.save()
```

I call a task in view

```
create.apply_async(eta.datetime(2019, 07, 31, 15, 56))
```

so far, everything is ok
but, if i need to revoke or edit this task is possible to connect it at my model like a ForeignKey?

ty

EDIT 1:

Suppose I send in queue a task for this afternoon at 15:30 and I tell it to create a model object.

After of this i need to edit something in that model object and the time of task is no more 15:30 but 16:30...

Now my model is:

```
class AuthorPrice(models.Model):
    author = models.Charfield(default=0)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    task = models.Charfield(default=0)
```

And my task is:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def create(self):

    print app.AsyncResult.task_id
    new = AuthorPrice.objects.create()
    new.author = 'John'
    new.task = app.AsyncResult.task_id
    new.save()
```

it write in db a task_id somethign like

```
<property object at 0x7fc77a397b50>
```

but it not work if i need to revoke it...

My goal is have a backup of task_id somewhere and revoke it when i change something in the task itselfes.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could create another task that 'undoes' the original task.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a task's id to whatever you like and use this id to revoke the task before it's processed

```
import uuid
task_id = uuid.uuid4()
create.apply_async(task_id=task_id)
some_data_storage.set(key, task_id)
```

When you want to revoke

```
task_id = some_date_storage.get(key)
AsyncResult(task_id).revoke()
```

Comment: but, in model how can I setup task_id?

Comment: It depends on how you're calling the tasks and why

Comment: You can't assign the task to the model because by the time the object is created the task has already run. When would you like to revoke the task?

Comment: so, if I need to revoke that task in second moment how can I find it?

Comment: Store the task_id somewhere that you can retrieve it when you want to revoke the task

Comment: When, why and how do you want to revoke it? Do you want a user to be able to do it?

Comment: For example: I send in queue a task for this afternoon at 15:30 and I tell it to create ad object author = John, price= 30. After of this i need to change the name of author from John to Mike and the time of task is no more 15:30 but 16:30... There is a way?

Comment: it write in db a task_id somethign like <property object at 0x7fc77a397b50>, any idea to revoke it?